# Porcentagem em Java

Tags: java

**Regra de negócio**: Um programa que recebe o codigo de um usuario, a qtd em KWh q ele consume e o tipo dele que podem ser 3: cada tipo multiplica o custo de energia consumida conforme estão definidas as constantes no início do programa, tudo isso enquanto o usuario não insira o código 0, ou seja, o programa vai recebendo mais dados enquanto o codigo digitado não seja 0. Por fim o programa deve devolver algumas coisas como o custo para cada usuario ( definidos unicamente por cada codigo inserido), o custo total para cada tipo inserido pelo programa até seu encerramento (o programa soma os custos para cada tipo), a media de custo para os usuarios do tipo 2 e por fim a porcentagem de usuarios do tipo 3 que utilizaram o programa.

Segue o código:

```
public class Problema01 {

    static double tipo1 = 1.5, tipo2 = 3.0, tipo3 = 5.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int entrada, tipo, codigo, qtd0 = 0, qtd = 0, qtd1 = 0, qtdTotal = 0;
        double porcentagem = 0, consumido, custoTotal, soma0 = 0, soma = 0, soma1 = 0, media = 0;

        do {

        System.out.println("Digite o código do consumidor: ");
                codigo = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Digite a quantidade consumida em KWh: ");
                consumido = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Digite o tipo de consumidor: ");
                tipo = sc.nextInt();

                if (tipo == 1) {
                    qtd0 = qtd0 + 1;
                    custoTotal = tipo1 * consumido;
                    soma0 = soma0 + custoTotal;
                    System.out.println("Valor da conta do usuário " + codigo + " é: " + custoTotal);

                } else if (tipo == 2) {
                    qtd = qtd + 1;
                    custoTotal = tipo2 * consumido;
                    soma = soma + custoTotal;
                    media = soma / qtd;
                    qtdTotal = qtd0 + qtd + qtd1;        
                    System.out.println("Valor da conta do usuário " + codigo + " é: " + custoTotal);
                } else if (tipo == 3) {
                    qtd1 = qtd1 + 1;
                    custoTotal = tipo3 * consumido;
                    soma1 = soma1 + custoTotal;                                       
                    System.out.println("Valor da conta do usuário " + codigo + " é: " + custoTotal);
                }

                qtdTotal = qtd0 + qtd + qtd1;
                porcentagem = qtd1 / qtdTotal * 100.0f;

                System.out.println("Total tipo 1: " + soma0);
                System.out.println("Total tipo 2: " + soma);
                System.out.println("Total tipo 3: " + soma1);
                System.out.println("Media custo tipo 2: " + media);
                System.out.println("Tipo 3 (em porcentagem): " + porcentagem + "%");

              }  while (codigo != 0);        

        }

    }
```

A última saída pede a porcentagem de usuários tipo 3 porém não está saindo corretamente. O que está errado?

**Exemplo de entrada:** 1,
                    10,
                    1,
**Saída:** Valor da conta do usuário 1 é: 15.0,
       Total tipo 1: 15.0,
       Total tipo 2: 0.0,
       Total tipo 3: 0.0,
       Media custo tipo 2: 0.0,
       Tipo 3 (em porcentagem): 0.0%

**Próxima entrada**:    2,
                    10,
                    3,
**Saída**: Valor da conta do usuário 2 é: 50.0,
       Total tipo 1: 15.0,
       Total tipo 2: 0.0,
       Total tipo 3: 50.0,
       Media custo tipo 2: 0.0,
       Tipo 3 (em porcentagem): 0.0%

Como no exemplo acima teve entrada um usuario do tipo 1 e depois um usuario do tipo 3, a minha saída esperada era 0% pela primeira entrada e 50% na segunda pois foram dois tipo sendo um deles o do tipo 3.

Comment: Tira o `f` do 100.0f;

Comment: ainda assim não funciona.

Comment: Qual o erro exatamente?

Comment: O que voce quer dizer com "nao funciona"? O que o código deveria fazer que nao faz?

Comment: ele ta retornando 0% mesmo quando um usuario do tipo 3 insere seus dados.

Comment: Informe um exemplo de entrada para poder testar o código da mesma forma que você está fazendo.

Comment: Acho que vc ta fazendo a conta errada, tá ficando 2 / 3 * 100, na realidade se vc quer dividir antes de multiplicar tem que colocar entre parentese (2/3) * 100

Comment: Fora que vc ta usando tipo int, isso invalida a conta

Comment: @Sorack entre multiplicação e divisão não precisa dessa separação, as operações são executadas na ordem que aparece.

Comment: Verdade, o problema tá na tipagem mesmo... se você colocar int ele arredonda entre a primeira e segunda operação

Comment: @Leko edite a pergunta e explique melhor o problema, o que deveria fazer que não faz? Até agora ninguem entendeu bem o real problema do código.

Comment: especifiquei melhor agora

Comment: Vou ser sincero contigo, estou tentando entender o que seu código faz ou deveria fazer mas está dificil...

Comment: Realmente, se você conseguir descrever a regra de negócio acho que dá pra ajudar bem mais

Comment: desculpe-me, sou iniciante e estou me empenhando para melhorar. Coloquei a regra de negócio na pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho que só a mudança do tipo ja resolve, mas se quiser a gente reve essa logica ai

Comment: tipo de qual variavel que eu devo mudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reescrevi o seu problema, porque apesar do erro ser devido a divisão de `int` por `int`,os nomes de variáveis confundiam. Então segui como padrão colocar o número referente ao tipo logo após o nome da variável. Também criei as variáveis apenas no escopo de uso delas. O resultado foi o seguinte:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Energia {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int codigo;

    int quantidade1 = 0;
    int quantidade2 = 0;
    int quantidade3 = 0;

    double multiplicador1 = 1.5;
    double multiplicador2 = 3;
    double multiplicador3 = 5;

    double total1 = 0;
    double total2 = 0;
    double total3 = 0;

    do {
      double consumido;
      int tipo;
      double custoTotal = 0;
      double quantidadeTotal;
      double porcentagem3;
      double media2 = 0;

      System.out.println("Digite o código do consumidor: ");
      codigo = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Digite a quantidade consumida em KWh: ");
      consumido = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Digite o tipo de consumidor: ");
      tipo = sc.nextInt();

      switch (tipo) {
        case 1:
          quantidade1 = quantidade1 + 1;
          custoTotal = multiplicador1 * consumido;
          total1 = total1 + custoTotal;
          break;
        case 2:
          quantidade2 = quantidade2 + 1;
          custoTotal = multiplicador2 * consumido;
          total2 = total2 + custoTotal;
          break;
        case 3:
          quantidade3 = quantidade3 + 1;
          custoTotal = multiplicador3 * consumido;
          total3 = total3 + custoTotal;
          break;
      }

      System.out.println("Valor da conta do usuário " + codigo + " é: " + custoTotal);

      quantidadeTotal = quantidade1 + quantidade2 + quantidade3;
      media2 = total2 / quantidade2;
      porcentagem3 = quantidade3 / quantidadeTotal * 100;

      System.out.println("Total tipo 1: " + total1);
      System.out.println("Total tipo 2: " + total2);
      System.out.println("Total tipo 3: " + total3);
      System.out.println("Media custo tipo 2: " + media2);
      System.out.println("Tipo 3 (em porcentagem): " + porcentagem3 + "%");
    } while (codigo != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: o switch ao invés do if foi o que corrigiu o problema?

Comment: Sugestão da IDE. Quando o if compara apenas um valor de variável o switch se torna mais adequado por ser mais legível

Comment: Deu certo? Em caso positivo confirme no "V" para que a resposta sirva para outras pessoas com dúvida similar

Comment: Fiz o seu código pelo if e deu certo desta vez,ao que parece iniciar algumas variaveis dentro do do...while corrigiu o problema mesmo sem eu entender o porque. se não for isso não sei dizer o que é o erro.

Comment: O tipo das variáveis ^^